# How to loop through an updating array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering

I am trying to practice `socket.io` with `React.js` so I am trying to send messages between two clients, however I'm struggling with displaying the messages. I want to show the past messages sent. Now I was thinking about doing it as an array because a state didn't work. When console logging the array it shows up in the console but never renders out

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import "./App.css";

let socket;
const CONNECTION_PORT = "localhost:3001/";

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  var itemArray = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    //connect to the socket
    socket = io(CONNECTION_PORT);

    socket.on("receive-message", (data) => {
      itemArray.push(data);
      console.log("Pong");
      console.log(itemArray);
    });

    //receiving messages
    socket.on("authentication", (bool) => {
      if (bool === true) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      }
    });
  }, [CONNECTION_PORT]);

  //Sending a request to join the room
  const connectToRoom = () => {
    socket.emit("join-room", room, userName);
  };

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send-message", message);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!loggedIn ? (
        <div className="login">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name..."
            onChange={(e) => {
              setUserName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Room..."
            onChange={(e) => {
              setRoom(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={connectToRoom}> Enter Chat</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Send Message..."
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMessage(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send Message</button>
          <div>
            {itemArray.map((data) => {
              console.log(data);
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is updating, but there is nothing to tell React to render the update. Any of these changes will cause the component to render again:

1. Update to props
2. Update to state
3. [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) value changes

> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state.

You are updating an array variable within the component, but this won't trigger a render. Move the array into state:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
    ...
    socket.on("receive-message", (data) => {
      // update the state which triggers a render
      setMessages(prevState => [...prevState, data]);
    });

}, [CONNECTION_PORT]);
```

Comment: okay this works when A sends a message it sends it and B receives but if B sends a message back it refreshes it multiple times

Comment: What do you mean it refreshes it multiple times? This sounds like the message is being emitted multiple times–`console.log` to determine that.

Comment: doesn't matter I changed the console logs. Now the results of this code is that when A sends multiple messages, it displays it and the one last message of B, but as soon as B sends a message it clears out A's messages. However for receiving the messages it replaces the last one and doesn't stack unlike for the sender

Comment: OK, but we are now on to a different issue which is correctly emitting messages to those in a room. The issue is not about `updating array in react` and having it render. *Both* clients need to receive the message (`receive-message`) so they can update their relevant state.

Comment: how? from what I understand ```...messages``` gets the last state of messages and adds the new data to the array? However in my case it doesn't get the last state on the received message it just adds it

Comment: It gets the last state on the relevant client and adds to it. If you not receiving the message on all clients, then their relevant state will not be updated–it's not a shared state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237803/discussion-between-james-westhead-and-samuel-goldenbaum).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return data to see it
Map returns each value you traverse so , you have to make sure say you want to see data like in a list
Please make sure to return  like this

Inside map function

```
{itemArray.map((data) => {
              return<li>{data.propertyName}</li>
            })}
```

Here property will be anything of an object property

Comment: the issue is that the component will not re-render if the `itemArray` variable is updated

Comment: Try using useEffect with second parameter as the updated array

Comment: Also an array is an object in JavaScript so changing it doesn't implies that the component will know that it's chnged , you need to use a flag and rsuch as reRender true false and use that as reference , this way it will see there was a chnage otherwise it won't affect in the prev one cause an object is still an object in JavaScript